# overflow-y hides page contents in a webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, overflow

I am currently making our website to be supported by all major browsers and I've met a very strange problem - oveflow-y attribute caused my data to be hidden. Below I've got an oversimplified code sample that works in IE and Firfox, but which doesn't work in Safari and Chrome. This is a 100% valid code and I am not sure why it doesn't display properly in webkit browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body style="height: 100%;">

<form action="Webkit_Problem.html" style="height: 100%;">
<table style="height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100%;">
                THIS SHOULD BE VISIBLE
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.alocet.com/VictorsTestFolder/Webkit_Problem.html (Live sample here)

The only way to get it working is either remove the height:100% attributes for div or a table tag (which will ruin the purpose of my html), or add height:100% to html tag

Does anyone has any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: `height: 100%;` results in a height of 0 pixels. What is it that you want to accomplish with 100% height?

Comment: In the real page which I am creating, height 100% is needed for a div, that is filled dynamically. Sometimes the div might contain one row of data, sometimes it may contain hundreds of rows of data, through which the user will need to scroll. No matter how much data this div has, it should still take up as much space as possible (to be consistent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that when you use `height: 100%;`, it sets your element height relative to its parent. This means that if your parent element does not have a height set, it will be automatically 0px height, or only the height of your content.

In order for your code to work, you need to set both the body and html to 100% height:

```
html, body{ height:100%; }
```

Comment: Well, that pretty much did work, though I do believe that there should be some other solution as well. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari 5.1 on Mac, apparently.  Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="Webkit_Problem.html" style="height: 100%;">
<table style="height: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 100%;">
                THIS SHOULD BE VISIBLE
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

You need to close the style attributes with quotation marks

Comment: Unfortunately, with doctype I've specified (which is a standard dtd) your html still doesn't display properly. For the quotation marks, it's my fault, I've copied it badly, but the version with proper quotation marks also doesn't work

Comment: meh. why are you using that doctype then?

Comment: Per HTML and XHTML standards, a DOCTYPE informs the validator which version of (X)HTML you’re using. DOCTYPEs are a key component of compliant web pages: your markup and CSS won’t validate without them.

DOCTYPES are also essential to the proper rendering and functioning of web documents in compliant browsers like Mozilla, IE5/Mac, and IE6/Win.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/